# отправка писем через SMTP yandex и попадание их в папку "Отправленные"

Tags: email, smtp, битрикс24

Всем привет!
Возникла необходимость отправлять письмо из PHP через SMTP яндекса. Если коротко, то надо, чтобы каждый пользователь имел возможность отправить письмо со своей почты через сайт (коробочный Bitrix24).
Отправляю командами SMTP через сокет (fscopen, далее fputs и результат считываю fread). Письмо отправляется и доходит до получателя, но не кладется в папку "Отправленные" яндекса. Отправка через PhpMailer приводит к тому же результату. Везде пишут, что так и должно быть - типа яндекс не кладет письма отправленные через его smtp в принципе, google кладет, но это его особенность, а не правило почтовиков.
Но, например, Thunderbird отправляет письма и они попадают в "отправленные" почты-отправителя. Тот же облачный Bitrix24 позволяет указать пользователю свой логин, пароль, настройки SMTP yandex и отправлять письма через Bitrix24. Письма кладутся в "Отправленные" у отправителя. То есть по идее есть какой-то способ закинуть их в отправленные.
Кто-нибудь знает как это сделать?

Comment: Используйте IMAP, а не SMTP. В [SMTP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321) подобный функционал не предусмотрен.

Comment: Это должен делать клиент, то есть вы, причём через IMAP. SMTP-сервер вообще имеет крайне смутное представление о каких-то там папках.

Comment: Да, выше все верно написали. Нужно вручную загрузить отправленное сообщение в Отправленные через IMAP. На C# работает код отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71435008/mailkit-mimekit-how-to-copy-to-sent-folder

Answer (score 0):

Я бы проверил эту галочку в настройках https://mail.yandex.ru/u2709/#setup/other

[image: скриншот]